# Obfuscate URLs in Android client application

Tags: java, android, smali

I wrote an android client app in which I am using static URLs to "post" to my server. I decompiled the APK using APKTool and found tht I could see the URL I mentioned in the .java code in the .smali file it generated. I want to avoid having this URL shown like this. Is there any way to hide /obfuscate the URL in the java code?

This is the sample from the decompiled .smali file.

```
invoke-direct {v8}, Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient;-><init>()V

.line 194
.local v8, httpclient:Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient;
new-instance v9, Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost;

const-string v23, "http://example.com/getdata.php"

move-object/from16 v0, v23

invoke-direct {v9, v0}, Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL can be obfuscated using things like encryption, base64 encoding and whatnot, but nothing you do to affect the client application can secure your URL.  A savvy programmer will always be able to identify what messages your application is sending out;  If you want security, secure the server, not the client